# Install R Cran package to local library location using apt

Tags: apt, package-management, r

How can I install to a custom library location using apt to install an R package?

I'm trying to install `dplyr` on a 1gb ram machine, and the usual `install.packages("dplyr",lib="/home/mycustomlib")` fails in compilation due to the small amount of memory. `sudo apt-get install r-cran-dplyr` works but how can I add a custom library location to the apt command installing R packages from cran?

Ideally there would be something like this (which does NOT work):

```
#DOES NOT WORK
sudo apt-get install r-cran-dplyr --lib="/home/mycustomlib"
```

Comment: You don't get to choose where deb package files install to. That is coded into the deb - dependencies NEED those files to be in an expected location. You would need to download and unpack the deb, alter it, and re-pack it back into a deb for installation by dpkg. Then you would need to ignore dpkg's security warning (signatures don't match). And, finally, the next update of the package would undo all your work and install to the standard location anyway, leaving your orphaned files littering the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me away from this rabbit hole. I ended up solving my issue by switching to the C and C++ compilers from this suggestion which worked brilliantly to solve my original problem of memory crash on dplyr install: _Originally posted by @rafaveguim in https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/262#issuecomment-248181871_